# Invoke Signed Mint To Instruction

Tags: solana-program, rust, pda, cpi

```
   if let Err(error) = invoke_signed(
        &SPLIX::mint_to_checked(
            token_program_account.key,
            contribution_mint_account.key,
            contribution_token_account.key,
            owner_account.key,
            &[&mint_and_freeze_auth],
            1,
            0
        )?,
        &[
            token_program_account.clone(),
            contribution_mint_account.clone(),
            contribution_token_account.clone(),
            owner_account.clone(),
            pda_freeze_auth.clone()
        ],
        &[signer_seeds]
    ) {
        return Err(error);
    }
```

Why does this not work? On intializing mint account i set the mint authroity to the PDA. and now to mint the token I need to pass the signer as the mint authority of course and from my web3 i'm getting the same PDA. The program says PDA's signer privilege escalated... Not sure what i'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

after checking the mint_to instruction in detail it doesn't check the owner key to be the owner of the account rather the mint authority on the mint account. Changing the owner key to the pda public key the CPI worked.
&SPLIX::mint_to_checked(
token_program_account.key,
contribution_mint_account.key,
contribution_token_account.key,
owner_account.key, // changing to pda_freeze_auth.key
&[&mint_and_freeze_auth],
1,
0
)?

same for in AcountInfo array removed the owner_account.clone() !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).